# Samba force permissions are ignored

Tags: samba

I am using Samba for quite some time on my server, without much trouble. However I tried it on NAS4Free(11.1.0.4 - Atomics (revision 4729)) today and run into the following problem:
I have a share with the following settings:

```
[HQ]
comment = Share for the HQ department
path = /mnt/zfs/HQ
writeable = yes
printable = no
veto files = /.snap/.sujournal/
hide dot files = yes
guest ok = no
inherit permissions = yes
inherit acls = yes
vfs objects = shadow_copy2 zfsacl recycle 
nfs4:mode = special
nfs4:acedup = merge
nfs4:chown = yes
recycle:repository = .recycle/%U
recycle:keeptree = yes
recycle:versions = yes
recycle:touch = yes
recycle:directory_mode = 0777
recycle:subdir_mode = 0700
shadow:format = auto-%Y%m%d-%H%M%S
shadow:snapdir = .zfs/snapshot
shadow:snapdirseverywhere = yes
shadow:sort = desc
shadow:localtime = yes
veto files = /.zfs/
valid users = @dsi-hq
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
force create mode = 0777
force directory mode = 0777
```

If I make a new file in a folder it has the following rights:
`-rwxrw-rw- 1 aron wheel 0 {date} {file}`

So even though I force creation mode 0777, I am somehow not able to execute the file. On top of that if another user tries to edit the file he gets permission denied.

More information:

Groups of user aron: dsi-hq

Groups of user mark: dsi-ict

Map structure: /mnt/hq/ict (aron has the share on hq and mark has the share on ict)

ICT share:

```
[ICT]
comment = Share for the ICT department
path = /mnt/zfs/HQ/ICT
writeable = yes
printable = no
veto files = /.snap/.sujournal/
hide dot files = no
guest ok = no
inherit permissions = yes
inherit acls = yes
vfs objects = shadow_copy2 zfsacl recycle 
nfs4:mode = special
nfs4:acedup = merge
nfs4:chown = yes
recycle:repository = .recycle/%U
recycle:keeptree = yes
recycle:versions = yes
recycle:touch = yes
recycle:directory_mode = 0777
recycle:subdir_mode = 0700
shadow:format = auto-%Y%m%d-%H%M%S
shadow:snapdir = .zfs/snapshot
shadow:snapdirseverywhere = yes
shadow:sort = desc
shadow:localtime = yes
veto files = /.zfs/
valid users = @dsi-ict
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
force create mode = 0777
force directory mode = 777
```